# How to incorporate adjacency matrix into equation (network simulation)

Tags: r, simulation, igraph

I've generated a small world network with 16 agents with `igraph`:

```
myNetwork <- sample_smallworld(dim = 1, nei = 1, size = 16, p = 0.1) #generate small world
plot(myNetwork, vertex.size=20, vertex.label=c(1:16), layout=layout_in_circle) #inspect the network
```

[image: this is myNetwork]

In a separate dataframe, `stack`, I have each of these agents' opinion (`opinion1`):

```
> stack
   agent   opinion1
1      1 0.71979146
2      2 0.25040406
3      3 0.50866647
4      4 0.53713674
5      5 0.53954982
6      6 0.23903034
7      7 0.03989347
8      8 0.29350197
9      9 0.85441826
10    10 0.44565889
11    11 0.28223782
12    12 0.39748249
13    13 0.17488017
14    14 0.08804374
15    15 0.61174168
16    16 0.30949636
```

I now want to calculate each `agent`'s updated opinion (let's call it `opinion2`) by applying this equation, where `networkNeighborsOpinion1` refers to the `opinion1`s of the agents that are connected in `myNetwork`:

```
opinion2 <- 0.5 * opinion1 * 0.5 * (mean(networkNeighborsOpinion1))
```

**Given `myNetwork` and `DF$opinion1`, how can I efficiently apply this equation to each agent?**

---

Here's my thinking so far...

From `myNetwork`, the corresponding adjacency matrix can be retrieved like so:

```
adjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(myNetwork, names = TRUE, edges = FALSE))
adjMatrix[adjMatrix == 0] <- NA #turn all 0s into NAs
```

```
> adjMatrix
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [2,]    1   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [3,]   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    1   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
[12,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     1    NA     1    NA    NA
[13,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA     1    NA     1    NA
[14,]   NA   NA    1   NA   NA    1   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA     1
[15,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
[16,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1
```

Each `agent` is represented by a row in `adjMatrix`, and each network connection is indicated by a value of `1`.

Then, it seems like there should be way to use each row of `adjMatrix` to call the appropriate values from `stack$opinion1` and generate a vector of `networkNeighborsOpinion1`, which could then be used to compute an `opinion2` for each agent. Note that I've changed the 0s in `adjMatrix` to NAs, which follows my thinking that each row could by multiplied by the corresponding values in `stack$opinion1` (i.e., each `opinion1` is either multiplied by 1 or NA, which could then be input as `mean(networkNeighborsOpinion1, na.rm = TRUE)`)

Any direction on this would be appreciated. Perhaps a `for` loop or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the adjacency matrix by `opinion1` and divide by the sum of corresponding rows in the adjacency matrix.  Then average that with `opinion1`.

```
adjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(myNetwork, names = TRUE, edges = FALSE))
0.5 * stack$opinion1 + 0.5 * (adjMatrix %*% stack$opinion1) / rowSums(adjMatrix)
```

### Note

`stack` is reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "   agent   opinion1
1      1 0.71979146
2      2 0.25040406
3      3 0.50866647
4      4 0.53713674
5      5 0.53954982
6      6 0.23903034
7      7 0.03989347
8      8 0.29350197
9      9 0.85441826
10    10 0.44565889
11    11 0.28223782
12    12 0.39748249
13    13 0.17488017
14    14 0.08804374
15    15 0.61174168
16    16 0.30949636"
stack <- read.table(text = Lines)
```